# VS2005 Class Library containing c code?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Can a Class Library be built containing c code? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

If by that you mean whether it's possible to write object oriented code in C, then yes. The first results from Google when searching for Object Oriented Programming in C:

[Object Oriented Programming in C](http://www.accu.informika.ru/acornsig/public/articles/oop_c.html)

[Object-Oriented Programming with ANSI C (PDF)](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

[ANSI C and object-oriented programming](http://barracudaserver.com/WP/DeviceControl/OOIntro.html)

I'm sure you can find the rest of the few hundred different papers on the topic.

A good example is the [GLib library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/).

Comment: Actually, I have c code with which I would like to a library, preferably a Class Library DLL. But I don't know if this is possible.

Alternatively, is there a way to package this code into a library which is accessible from a VS2008 solution?

Comment: It's still highly unclear what you mean. Even more unclear, if that was possible. Perhaps you could rephrase your question?